# What does '{}' mean in following coffee script code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

```
{CompositeDisposable} = require 'atom'
```

Found the line in generated atom plugin scaffold code. The code basically collect all so called 'subscriptions' and put them into one class to be disposed altogether.

I can't find anything similar in coffeescript manual, can anyone please tell me what's going on with the curly brackets?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you!

Comment: Note that it was the first hit on Google for *"coffeescript curly brackets"*...